# Insert multiple rows in mysql using jquery repeater

Tags: javascript, php, forms, jquery.repeater

I have a form repeater (https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) that adds multiple inputs if needed, but the only thing is.. i don't know how to make'it to insert in sql all the data from form at once. So here's what i have so far, sorry for my bad English, I am a learner and u guys are the best.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="repeater-default">
            <div data-repeater-list="sectiuni" class="col-md-12">
              <div data-repeater-item="">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group mb-1 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <label for="email-addr">Sectiunea</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sectiunea" name="sectiunea[]" placeholder="Introdu sectiunea">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mb-1 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                    <label for="pass">Nr.Dansatori</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="nrdansatori[]" id="nrdansatori" placeholder="Numarul dansatorilor">
                  </div>
                  <div class="skin skin-flat form-group mb-1 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                    <label for="tel-input">Timp piesa</label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="timpsectiune[]" id="timpsectiune" placeholder="2:34">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group mb-1 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                    <label for="pret">Pret</label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="pretsectiune[]" id="pretsectiune" placeholder="250">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-2 mt-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 12px;" data-repeater-delete=""> <i
                        class="feather icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group overflow-hidden">
              <div class="col-12">
                <button type="button" data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12 btn-sm">
                  <i class="feather icon-plus"></i> ADD ONE MORE SECTION
                </button> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close">
          <input type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#save").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sectiunea    = $("#sectiunea").val();
        var nrdansatori  = $("#nrdansatori").val();
        var timpsectiune = $("#timpsectiune").val();
        var pretsectiune = $("#pretsectiune").val();
        var infos = {
            sectiunea   : sectiunea,
            nrdansatori : nrdansatori,
            timpsectiune: timpsectiune,
            pretsectiune: pretsectiune
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: infos,
            url: 'sql-insert.php',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === TRUE) {
                    alert('Success'); 
                } else {
                     alert("ERROR");
                }
            }
       });
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['sectiunea'])) {
    $table = "`".RDCP_PREFIX."sectiuni`";
        $data = array(
            'sectiune' => trim($db->escape($_POST['sectiunea'])),
            'max_d'    => trim($db->escape($_POST['nrdansatori'])),
            'timp'     => trim($db->escape($_POST['timpsectiune'])),
            'pret'     => trim($db->escape($_POST['pretsectiune']))
          );
          foreach ($data as $name) {
         
         $db->insert($table, $data);
          
        }
    } 
public function insert($table,$fields) { 
$field = array_keys($fields); 
$single_field = implode(",", $field); 
$val = implode("','", $fields); 
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$table."(".$single_field.") VALUES('".$val."')"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
if($stmt === true) { echo true; } 
else { echo false; } 
}
```

Comment: Yes is related bcz has to pass form jquery repeater to ajax , i think

Comment: My answer is only focusing on the mysql/php interactions.. that sounds like the root of the problem though

Comment: Thank you a lott, i will test'it now

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` function is likely the issue. You are inserting each column into its own record, you also are misusing prepared statements. You should write the function something like this (pseudo code below):

```
public function insert($table, $array) { 
    $fields = array_keys($array); 
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(' . implode(",", $fields) .') VALUES (' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($fields), '?')) .')'); 
    $stmt->bind_param(implode('', array_fill(0, count($fields), 's')), ...array_values($array));
    $stmt->execute(); 
    if($stmt === true) { 
        echo true; 
    } else { 
        echo false; 
    } 
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50654198/3783243 for potential `bind_param` issues.

Then call it like:

```
if(isset($_POST['sectiunea'])) {
    $table = "`".RDCP_PREFIX."sectiuni`";
    $data = array(
            'sectiune' => trim($_POST['sectiunea']),
            'max_d'    => trim($_POST['nrdansatori']),
            'timp'     => trim($_POST['timpsectiune']),
            'pret'     => trim($_POST['pretsectiune'])
          );
     $db->insert($table, $data);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot unpack array with string keys

Comment: Opps, can you try with updated `array_values` function?

Comment: yep, now i got this: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Comment: What does `var_dump(implode('', array_fill(0, count($fields), 's')), ...array_values($array));` give back?

Comment: string(4) "ssss" string(5) "test1" string(2) "33" string(5) "23:55" string(2) "33"

Comment: That should be correct, although may have jumped gun `var_dump($stmt)` is false? Do you have mysqli exceptions on?

Comment: Check my answer, bellow

Comment: If you provide a sample of `$_POST` you likely want to iterate over one of the indices for those, then use that numeric key for the other indices. This way you won't iterate over other `POST` values, if there are..

Answer (score 0):

I think i have done'it with this and is working bcz jquery repeater does the names like this cat[0]name:

```
if(!empty(isset($_POST))) {
    $table = "`".RDCP_PREFIX."sectiuni`";
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        for ($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++) {
            $data = array(
                'sectiune' => $value[$i]['sectiunea'],
                'max_d'    => $value[$i]['nrdansatori'],
                'timp'     => $value[$i]['timpsectiune'],
                'pret'     => $value[$i]['pretsectiune']
              );
          $db->insert($table, $data);
        }
    }  
}
```